# spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion ignored

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jackson, spring-autoconfiguration

In my Spring Boot/Kotlin project, I am trying to get the JSON converter to ignore null values in my rest controller responses.

I've tried setting the following in my application.yml:

```
spring:
    jackson:
        default-property-inclusion: non_null
```

I've also tried providing a `@Bean` of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and `@ObjectMapper` configured with `.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` but it's still serializing all the null properties.

Using Spring Boot 2.3.0, Kotlin 1.3.72, AdoptOpenJDK 13

Answer (score 6):

Well, I found the problem by creating a new project from scratch and adding pieces from the current one until I got the aberrant behavior.

Turns out the problem was in a class used to add CORS mappings:

```
@EnableWebMVC
@Configuration
class WebConfiguration : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
    }
}
```

I think I added `@EnableWebMVC` as seen in an example, but the class is not in the same part of the class hierarchy as the `@RESTController` classes, so it looks like that's why the object mapper configuration wasn't being applied. I don't know enough about the internal wiring of Spring/Boot to tell you why.

Once I removed `@EnableWebMVC` and allowed Spring Boot to add it to the application class through Autoconfiguration, it worked as expected...

Comment: Thank you for this!! Was about to do the same (start from scratch), but found your answer just in time! For me it was the `@EnableWebFlux` annotation that did it, but the result was the same. But how did you manage CORS then?

Comment: Man I have read tons and tons of tutorials how to set the `default-property-inclusion` but none of them worked because of that annotation. I'll try to find the tutorial from which I configured the CORS and leave a comment there to prevent future headaches for developers. Huge tanks to you, have my upvote!

Comment: @TerjeAndersen I just removed the `@EnableWebMVC` annotation and everything worked fine. The configuration class that registered the CORS mappings still works. The annotation enables a bunch of default settings for web mvc but it's not necessary in order to use `@RestController`s, etc.

Comment: thank you!  be nice to know _why_ it works